# html break a line once or more

Tags: html, layout

I have a table. One column contains pairs of dates, e.g.

```
2014/01/01 -
2014/01/02
```

I don't want this, because then the column is too wide:

```
2014/01/01 - 2014/01/02
```

I can't do this:

```
html
2014/01/01 - <br /> 2014/01/02
```

Because that causes this:

```
2014/01/01
-
2014/01/02
```

So the line needs to be broken exactly once. Any ideas?

Comment: That shouldn't result in that output, can you supply a fiddle?

Comment: Your last example makes it look like you could solve the problem by simply increasing the width by a very small amount. Apparently the `-` doesn't fit in the first line. So whatever you use to break the lines, it will not get you your desired result unless you give the first line enough space. But as @Pyro said, seeing the code would help a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's where *non breaking space* comes handy. Try this:

```
2014/01/01&nbsp;-<br>2014/01/02
```

In this case dash `-` should never end up on the next line.

Compare the behavior when it's not enough space in this **[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DL1fDKP28DtAJxZ8DJ0K?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 3):

`<span style="white-space:nowrap;">2014/01/01 -</span> 2014/01/02`

Or you could try the older `<nobr>2014/01/01 -</nobr> 2014/01/02`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this error, when I use this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>2014/01/01 -
            <br />2014/01/02</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I get the expexted output:

```
2014/01/01 -
2014/01/02
```

But you could use `white-space:nowrap` in your CSS:

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the <pre> element to control formatting exactly (as in, whitespace including newlines will be rendered exactly as it is in the HTML source, between the open and close tags). It's kind of hacky but should work for this.

```
<pre>2014/01/01 -
2014/01/02</pre>
```